# Gatsby reusable components with own query

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

Is it currently possible in Gatsby to build reusable components that have their own graphql query? If not, currently what is the least "coupled" way to pass data to reusable components? I can't seem to find any examples that do this and I can't find anything in the documentation.

Say, for example, you want to make a tag cloud component for a blog that would show up in the side bar of all "post" pages as well as on a single "/tag-cloud" page. You could use like `<TagCloud limit={20} />` or `<TagCloud tags={uniqueTags} />`. For this, you would need to query all edges, map-reduce/extract each `tags` array down to a unique, ordered set of unique tag strings.

Or, say you wanted an "other products" component for a catalog page that excludes the current product. Here, you might have `<ProductsList exclude={currentProduct} />`. This would be a straight-forward filtered query at build-time.

The only way I can see doing this is either to monkey-patch the query results from `createPages()` or to pass data through `context` in `createPage({path, component, context})`. Should this take place in `gatsby-node.js`? Are there any other ways?

Comment: Quick answer is fragments https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=fragment&type= Hopefully I'll have time to write up docs on this soon.

Comment: Thanks @KyleMathews (and many thanks for Gatsby). I will investigate and update when I am done.

Comment: @KyleMathews -- still not seeing it. Fragments (in queries) seem to only receive a single graphql edge that they expand. I don't see any example that can access, for example, `allMarkdownRemark`. For the avatar example, as another e.g., how would you show a list of all avatars of all site authors on a single post page? Or, if I can build a list in `gatsby-node.js`, how should I pass that to all pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question. If someone has a better solution, please submit it and I will gladly accept it.

My current solution, which I referenced in my question and I think is suboptimal, is to build all of the data required for top-level reusable components in `pages/index.js` (or anywhere you use `createPage({path, component, context})` and inject the data into `context`. This makes it available to the `component` constructor via the `pathContext` property. The name, `pathContext` makes me think this is an abuse of spirit of this object, but it gets the job done.

For example, if you had a blog whose entries could have an array of tags, this might be your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

const getUniqueTags = edges => {
    const set = new Set();

    edges.forEach(edge => edge.node.frontmatter.tags.forEach(tag => set.add(tag)));

    return [...set];
};

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, boundActionCreators }) => resolve(graphql(`
        query AllPagesQuery {
            allMarkdownRemark {
                edges {
                    node {
                        frontmatter {
                            path
                            tags
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `)))
    .then(({ errors, data }) => {
        const { createPage } = boundActionCreators;
        const pageTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/page.js');

        if (errors) return Promise.reject(errors);

        return data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(edge => {
            createPage({
                path: edge.node.frontmatter.path,
                component: pageTemplate,
                context: {
                    path: edge.node.frontmatter.path,
                    tags: getUniqueTags(data.allMarkdownRemark.edges)
                }
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Then your `templates/page.js` could receive the unique tags array like this:

```
const IndexPage = ({ pathContext }) => {
    const { tags } = pathContext.map(tag => <li>{ tag }</li>);

    return <div>{ tags }</div>;
};

export default IndexPage;
```

Comment: I find myself implementing the same method. It would be great to here from @KyleMathews if there is any danger with this method or to explain how fragments could be used to achieve the same result.

Comment: It's hard to know more without seeing your data model (or knowing your source plugin), but ideally you'd get all the tags from GraphQL directly via the `pageQuery` in each page component. This shows the general approach https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/docs/docs/building-with-components.md#page-template-components

Answer (score 3):

You can create a fragment query in your layouts/index.js

```
export const avatarsFragmentQuery = graphql`
  fragment avatars on RootQueryType {
    avatars: allImageSharp {
      edges {
        node {
           id

         }
       }
    }
  }
`
```

And use it in your pages:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogQuery {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }

    ...avatars
  }
`
```